# Split Two Dimensional Array into n more based on key value

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, split

i've been busting my head over this array:

```
Array (
    [invoicenr] => Array (  
                            [0] => 1234 
                            [1] => 1234 
                            [2] => 1234 
                            [3] => 4321 
                            [4] => 3214
                        ) 
    [invoicedate] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 17.07.2017. 
                            [1] => 17.07.2017. 
                            [2] => 17.07.2017. 
                            [3] => 11.07.2017. 
                            [4] => 11.07.2017. ) 
    [amount] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 10 
                            [1] => 1 
                            [2] => 23 
                            [3] => 10 
                            [4] => 1 ) 
    [cause] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 1 
                            [1] => 1 
                            [2] => 1 
                            [3] => 1 
                            [4] => 1 ) 
)
```

I'm trying to split array above based on 1st level key "invoicenr" value, but without luck so far.
I'm expecting result:

```
Array (
       [invoicenr] => Array (  
                             [0] => 1234 
                             [1] => 1234 
                             [2] => 1234) 
       [invoicedate] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 17.07.2017. 
                             [1] => 17.07.2017. 
                             [2] => 17.07.2017.) 
       [amount] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 10 
                             [1] => 1 
                             [2] => 23) 
       [cause] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 1 
                             [1] => 1 
                             [2] => 1) 
            ) 
Array (
       [invoicenr] => Array (   
                             [0] => 4321 ) 
       [invoicedate] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 11.07.2017. ) 
       [amount] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 10) 
       [cause] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 1  ) 
        )
Array (
       [invoicenr] => Array (   
                             [0] => 3214 ) 
       [invoicedate] => Array (
                             [0] => 11.07.2017. ) 
       [amount] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 1) 
       [cause] => Array ( 
                             [0] => 1  ) 
        )
```

I want to know if this is possible and how, or i need to rewrite array first?

Thank you all in advance, i'm new into coding and struggling to learn so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please post the code you attempted to solve the problem with.

I believe you will need a counter (i) to go through invoicenr and a temporary variable that remembers the last value (Array[i]) and compares it with the next value in the array of invoicenr. If the value is the same you keep going, and if it is different you print out all the other arrays[i].

Answer (score 0):

i've finnaly did it, but i think my way is too primitive. Here is what i did:

```
//Count number of rows in initial array
$rows = count(array_filter($_POST['invoicenr']));
//Crete unique array that contains only $_POST['invoicenr'] which i can count later
$uniquearray = array();
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) { 
    $uniquearray[] = $_POST['invoicenr'][$row] ;
}
//return unique keys only
$invoicenrunique=array_keys(array_flip($uniquearray));
//count number of rows in unique array
$invoicenruniquecount=count(array_keys(array_flip($uniquearray)));
//do magic, this splits main array into n smaller arrays based on $_POST['invoicenr']
for($uniquerow = 0; $uniquerow < $invoicenruniquecount; $uniquerow++)   {
    $testarray = array();
    for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) { 
        if($_POST['invoicenr'][$row]==$invoicenrunique[$uniquerow]){
            $testarray[$row]['invoicenr']=$_POST['invoicenr'][$row];
            $testarray[$row]['invoicedate']=$_POST['invoicedate'][$row];
            $testarray[$row]['amount']=$_POST['amount'][$row];
            $testarray[$row]['cause']=$_POST['cause'][$row];
        } 
    }
    print_r(array_values($testarray));
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to improve my solution?

Best regards!